# Yoga framework partial response default response without selector parameter

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-mvc, gdata

We're using Yoga Framework for partial response at our api project. It works very well with Spring-MVC. But if  we send a request without selector parameter, it returns an empty json object or just @Core attributes. What should we do to return all attributes if selector parameter at the URI is empty?

We used [this](https://github.com/skyscreamer/yoga/wiki/Tutorial%3a-SpringMVC) tutorial to configure the project.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? We're trying to do this too, but the closest we've come to is getting all the fields for a specific level of the object tree.

Comment: Check this issue. https://github.com/skyscreamer/yoga/pull/240

Comment: I've checked this page already, and that's how i was able to get fields in a specific level, but still not able to get everything